# How to do complex query on big data?

Tags: hadoop, hive

every one.
I have some data about 6G in hdfs that has been exported from mysql.And I have write mapreduces prehandling data to fill some key field that data can be easily queried.
As the business demands are different aggregation data group by day ,hour,hospital,area etc,
so I have to write many hive sqls exporting data to local disk,and then I write python script to parse files on local disk ,then get datas in demand.

Is there some good technique on hadoop to resolve my demand.I am considering.
Can you help me ,please.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @climbage,my question is that using hive got datas and then parsing lots of data to get datas in demand is a complex way .Is there a better   solution to do it . : )

Comment: 6G is not big deal with hive.Hive can easily solve your problem,can you explain exact problem.

Comment: As one record in demand need to call 3 or more hive queries to generate datas on disk.After that I use python parsing and merging datas to one record.I felt this way is stupid.Is there a better solution?